# Python Logistic Regression error : "TypeError: issubclass() arg 2 must be a class or tuple of classes"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, sklearn-pandas

I'm creating a multiclass classification model with 4 possible outcomes.  it worked yesterday but today, I receive the error below.  I'm not very familiar with Python so any help in regards to how to fix this is appreciated.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

Logistic=LogisticRegression()
logistic.fit(X_train_scaled,y_train)
y_pred_log=logistic.predict(X_test_scaled)
log_cm=(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_log))
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-213-8e436855d9cc> in <module>
      1 logistic=LogisticRegression()
----> 2 logistic.fit(X_train_scaled,y_train)
      3 y_pred_log=logistic.predict(X_test_scaled)
      4 log_cm=(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_log))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   1491         The SAGA solver supports both float64 and float32 bit arrays.
   1492         """
-> 1493         solver = _check_solver(self.solver, self.penalty, self.dual)
   1494 
   1495         if not isinstance(self.C, numbers.Number) or self.C < 0:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py in _check_solver(solver, penalty, dual)
    430         warnings.warn("Default solver will be changed to 'lbfgs' in 0.22. "
    431                       "Specify a solver to silence this warning.",
--> 432                       FutureWarning)
    433 
    434     all_solvers = ['liblinear', 'newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'sag', 'saga']

TypeError: issubclass() arg 2 must be a class or tuple of classes
```

Comment: add some artificial data

Comment: I'm not familiar with what would be needed to further explain the question.

Comment: we need the `X, y` to reproduce the error

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your solver is causing the error. Try changing your solver:

```
solver = 'lbfgs'
```